# Magento 2: ko Select select default value

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

How to select default value in select in magento 2 and show same in checkout page

```
<select class="pro-subscription__options-list" name="pro-subscription_type" data-validate="{'required':true}">
<option id="pro-option-21" value="21">Starter</option>
<option id="pro-option-22" value="22">Essential</option>
<option id="pro-option-23" value="23">Plus</option>
<option id="pro-option-24" value="24">Pro</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes I tried but select have some ko binging for change event which didn't work with simple jquery

Comment: Starter is showing by default but not working as selected